# How do I create a Matplotlib bar chart with categories?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a matplotlib bar chart with categories on the X-axis, but I can't get the categories right. Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do.

```
data = [[46, 11000], [97, 15000], [27, 24000], [36, 9000], [9, 17000]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['car_id', 'price'])

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax1.set_title('Car prices')
ax1.bar(df['car_id'], df['price'])
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df)), list(df['car_id']))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I need the five categories (car_id) on the X-axis. What Am I doing wrong? :-/

Answer (score 3):

You can turn `car_id` into `category`:

```
df['car_id'] = df['car_id'].astype('category')

df.plot.bar(x='car_id')
```

Output:

[image]

You can also plot just the `price` column and relabel:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(y='price')
ax.set_xticklabels(df['car_id'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You got confused in the xticks with the label and position. Here you specify the position `np.arange(len(df))` and the labels `list(df['car_id']`. So he puts the labels at the specified position `list(df['car_id']`, i.e. `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])`.

If the position and the labels are here the same, just replace `plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df)), list(df['car_id']))` by `plt.xticks(df['car_id'])`.

If you want them to be evenly spaced, your approach is right but you also need to change `ax1.bar(df['car_id'], df['price'])` to`ax1.bar(np.arange(len(df)), df['price'])`, so that the bar x-position is now evenly spaced.

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

data = [[46, 11000], [97, 15000], [27, 24000], [36, 9000], [9, 17000]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['car_id', 'price'])

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax1.set_title('Car prices')
ax1.bar(np.arange(len(df)), df['price'])
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(df['car_id'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you Liris, that helped me with the categories being placed below the bars. But it seems as if the categories are still being interpreted as numeric values and not categories. Because they are stille thin plots with different spacing.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. There's still some "logic" around Matplotlib I need to figure out apparently. :-)